# Android:tags for RSS feed parsing

Tags: android, xml, tags, rss

Here is my RSS feed im trying to parse

```
<PetrolPrices>
<Fuel type="Unleaded">
<Highest units="p">132.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">128.8</Average>
<Lowest units="p">125.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Fuel type="Diesel">
<Highest units="p">137.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">132.4</Average>
<Lowest units="p">129.7</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Fuel type="Super Unleaded">
<Highest units="p">142.9</Highest>
<Average units="p">137.7</Average>
<Lowest units="p">132.9</Lowest>
</Fuel>
<Link>
http://www.petrolprices.com/search.html?search=Glasgow
</Link>
</PetrolPrices>
```

the problem is this is very different from any xml ive ever parsed i mean most of the time its a simple

```
<title>
"The Title"
</title>
```

My question is which what are the tag names i should be using and also how is it possible to get the fuel tag since its used when im trying to get the other tags. Basically i want it parsed like below

```
Type is = "Unleaded
       Highest units = 132.9
       Average units = 128.8
       Lowest units = 125.9
```

*after all other tags are done

```
link = http://www.petrolprices.com/feeds/averages.xml?search_type=town&search_value=glasgow
```

Edit: this is the code i use to parse the data

```
    package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
//import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetrolPriceActivity extends ListActivity 
{
    static final String KEY_FUEL = "Fuel"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    static final String KEY_HIGHEST = "Highest";
    static final String KEY_AVERAGE = "Average";
    static final String KEY_LOWEST = "Lowest";
    private TextView errorText;
    private String petrolPriceURL;
    private static final String TAG = "PetrolPrice";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
        petrolPriceURL =extras.getString("URLString");

        }
        // Get the TextView object on which to display the results
        new asyncTask().execute(petrolPriceURL);

     }

    // End of onCreate


public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> 

{
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PetrolPriceActivity.this);

        @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
          dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
          dialog.setProgress(0);
          dialog.setMax(100);
          dialog.setMessage("loading...");
          dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String...params) 

        {

            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
           {
                publishProgress(1);
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            String urlString = petrolPriceURL;
            String result = "";
            InputStream anInStream = null;
            int response = -1;
            URL url = null;

            try 
            {
                url = new URL(urlString);
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return null;
            }

            URLConnection conn = null;
            try 
            {
                conn = url.openConnection();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                return null;
            }

            // Check that the connection can be opened
            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return null;
                }
            }

            try 
            {
                // Open connection
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                // Check that connection is OK
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                {
                    // Connection is OK so open a reader
                    anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                    BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                    // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                    String line = new String();
                    while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                    {

                        result = result + line;
                    }
                }

                        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                        Handler parser = new Handler();
                        String xml = result; // getting XML
                        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);


                        // getting DOM element

                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);
                        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + nl.getLength());

                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
                        {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(KEY_TYPE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TYPE));
                            map.put(KEY_HIGHEST, "Highest units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                            map.put(KEY_AVERAGE, "Average units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                            map.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Lowest units = " +parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            menuItems.add(map);
                            Log.v(TAG, "index1=" + menuItems);
                        }
            }


            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    throw new IOException("Error connecting");

                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }
            return menuItems;

           }
           @Override

           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress)
           {

               dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> menuItems) 
           {

               errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
               TextView linkView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.link);


               try
                {
                   //Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
                   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PetrolPriceActivity.this, menuItems,
                   R.layout.list_content,

                   new String[] { KEY_TYPE, KEY_HIGHEST, KEY_AVERAGE, KEY_LOWEST}, new int[] {
                   R.id.fuel, R.id.highest, R.id.average, R.id.lowest});

                   Log.v(TAG, "index2=" + menuItems);



                   setListAdapter(adapter);


                }
                catch(Exception ae)
                {
                    // Handle error
                    // Add error info to log for diagnostics
                    errorText.setText(ae.toString());
                } 
                linkView.setText(petrolPriceURL);
                Log.v(TAG, "indexppu=" + petrolPriceURL);

                if(dialog.getProgress() == dialog.getMax())
                dialog.dismiss();

          }

}
    // End of petrolPriceString
 // End of Activity class
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Use XMLPullParser

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL(
                "http://www.petrolprices.com/feeds/averages.xml?search_type=town&search_value=glasgow");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Fuel");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Element nameElement1 = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

            System.out.println("type : "+ nameElement1.getAttribute("type"));        // Here we are getting type Attribute Value

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "type = "
                    + nameElement1.getAttribute("type"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Highest");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Highest = "
                    + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.v("Highest--", ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Average");
            Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
            websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

            Log.v("Average--", ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Lowest");
            websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
            websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

            Log.v("Lowest--", ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Change this..

```
map.put(KEY_TYPE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TYPE));
```

to

```
map.put(KEY_TYPE, e.getAttribute(KEY_TYPE));
```

Comment: no no i have all the code it was simply what tags i should be using... also how to make link appear as one object rather than in the ListView

Comment: these are the tags i have at the moment.... static final String KEY_FUEL = "Fuel"; // parent node
 static final String KEY_HIGHEST = "Highest";
 static final String KEY_AVERAGE = "Average";
 static final String KEY_LOWEST = "Lowest";

Comment: @user3071845 You can see from this like inside for loop `nameElement1.getAttribute("type")` we can get attribute value.