# Android:how to get a value from a RSS feed and subtract it from a value in another RSS feed

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

Hey i have these two RSS feeds - http://www.petrolprices.com/feeds/averages.xml?search_type=town&search_value=kilmarnock and http://www.petrolprices.com/feeds/averages.xml?search_type=town&search_value=glasgow. Now what i want to do is take a value from one RSS feed and calculate it with a value from the other RSS feed. So for example

132.9 - 133.1

How would i go about doing this?

The basic idea is that the user creates the RSS URLs and then the onClick takes all the values from each of the RSS feeds and compares it against the other so that the user gets the difference so the overall money saved by selecting one or the other

Comment: Do you have an algorithm to find "the overall money saved," which you need specific guidance in implementing against petrolprices' RSS feeds, or are you also seeking help developing that algorithm?

Comment: @newcoder i need help in developing the code needed to take a value from an RSS feed and then store this value in an integer value and then do the same from another RSS feed and then do some calculation with these

Comment: i do know how to get the money saved its a simple subtraction from the higher value of the RSS feed and the lower value which then gives you the money saved by selecting one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, your question has a simple answer, and a more specifically helpful answer. I'll state the simple answer of how to convert character data to a number (whether an int, double, float, etc.) first for the record, specifically focusing on the exception cases, then delve into the detail that specifically applies to your problem.

Any time you have a String representation of something you believe is a certain type of number, you can call the appropriate valueOf() or parseXYZ() method for the target wrapper class. E.g. if you're looking for an integer: theInt is the String "42". Integer.valueOf(theInt) would return an Integer with the value 42, and Integer.parseInt(theInt) would return int 42.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html

If theInt represented, say, "forty-two" or "42.0" either method would throw NumberFormatException. Parsing a floating-point number follows much the same process, except that "42.0" would parse correctly, and "42.0.0" will throw a NumberFormatException on Android. The whole string passed to one of these methods must be a valid number of the chosen type. Whitespace at the end will also throw the exception.

If you're using a Scanner, you can use hasNextXYZ() and nextXYZ() to check for and get the next number, where XYZ can be any of the primitive types. The Scanner will operate on the next token, which it will define based on the delimiters you have set.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html

**"Great, so when, where, and how should one take the numbers in the XML and pass them to any of the above methods?"** You should have a data structure to hold each value, which you populate as the XML is being parsed. Based on the state of things over at [your related question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387332/androidtags-for-rss-feed-parsing) it is my understanding that parsing the XML into tokens has been solved. Therefore, update your parser to call the right String-to-number conversion method for the values of highest, average, and lowest elements. The Strings you need are already correctly trimmed and are passing through the parser at each stage.

Or, to decouple your code further, create an object the hold the data sets you will be comparing, then have the parser simply instantiate and call setters. FuelData could be that object.

```
class FuelData { 
    String KEY_TYPE;
    double highest;
    double average;
    double lowest;
    // if future support for currency types needed, would go here, hook in to units attribute in xml
    FuelData(String type) { // call this every time a type is encountered parsing html
        KEY_TYPE = type;
    }

    void setHighest(String val) { // here, val is value of "Highest" element
        try {
            highest = Double.parseDouble(val); // because you're not using a Scanner to parse
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // handle appropriately
        }
        // perhaps sanity check: disallow negatives, check not less than lowest, etc.
    }

    // and so on for average and lowest

    double computeSavings(FuelData pricesB) { // called by onClick
    // your subtraction goes here. Perhaps you decide it's reasonable to use this method
    // to compute savings for Regular vs. Premium and therefore do not check type,
    // perhaps you decide that's illogical and do check types.
    // Note: good arguments can be made that this method should exist in a different
    // class. I've placed it here for simplicity's sake.
    }
}
```

Collect the FuelData in a logical way, that can be accessed after parsing has finished, such as feed1 being parsed into a Set of FuelData, feed2 to a set of FuelData, etc, then have onClick take all the FuelData that was parsed out of each of the RSS feeds, do the comparisons via computeSavings, and return the results.

Comment: great answer very easy to understand and im sure will help me greatly